# Elementary polynomial-free proofs of fundamental theorem of Galois theory?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

I am looking for simple proofs that show the correspondence between intermediate fields in a field extension and subgroups of the Galois group. I'm happy for everything to be subfields of $\mathbb{C}$.

An example of the kind of statement I would like to see is Theorem 1.1 of Mita Boyarchenko's paper, [Galois Theory via Wedderburn Theory](https://web.archive.org/web/20100607202912/http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/seminars/kottwitz/Galois.pdf)  .

There, Boyarchenko shows for instance that if $L$ is a field, $G\subset \text{Aut}(L)$ a finite subgroup, $K =  L^G$ the set of elements of $L$ fixed by $G$, then

(a) $\text{dim}_KL = |G|$

(b) The maps $F\mapsto \text{Aut}(L/F)$ and $H\mapsto L^H$ are bijections between intermediate fields $K\subset F\subset L$ and subgroups $H$ of $G$. Here, $\text{Aut}(L/F)$ is the automorphisms of $L$ that fix each element of $F$.

(c) Let $F$ be any intermediate field between $K$ and $L$, and suppose $g(F)\subset F$ for all $g\in G$. Then the restriction map $\text{Aut}(L/K) \to \text{Aut}(F/K)$ is surjective with kernel $\text{Aut}(L/F)$.

Boyarchenko's proof, however, requires some fairly heavy-weight machinery. Isn't there some simple way to see at least some of these facts, without going deep into separable extensions and irreducible/minimal, polynomials, or Wedderburn theory?

Comment: Good luck finding more by "pure thought" than is in Kaplansky's treatment.

Comment: I have seen all these results in my 2nd year of university. It was very nice and not so hard (but took a few months). So there should be some nice references.

Comment: The absolute shortest proof I know is the route taken by Yoshida in his "minimal" notes on Galois theory: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/2010_Galois_M24/Galois_min.pdf Is this the kind of thing you want? I don't really understand what "polynomial-free" means here. Why would you want to do Galois theory without talking about polynomials? 

Comment: The Yoshida paper looks interesting, thanks, although I am not sure its statement is quite as strong as the one in Boyarchenko (claim (a) above). The reason I do not like the polynomial development is
 that there is too much notation, special cases (multiple roots, separability, irreducibility over various fields), and theorems about polynomial division that doesn't seem to fit with the simple, abstract statement of the theorem. The Boyarchenko proof is much cleaner - can it be made elementary?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: It depends what you mean by Galois Theory, but the essential ideas, at least, are useful in a more general setting than polynomials. In fact, you don't even need to mention fields to set down the main ingredients of Galois Theory. See, for example, [Bill Lampe's notes](http://math.hawaii.edu/~williamdemeo/612_Galois.pdf). The basic notion of a Galois connection, while not "Galois Theory" per se, shows up all over, and can be quite useful in areas unrelated to polynomials. 

Comment: @William: I am aware of this, but the hardest part of understanding any Galois connection is finding out what each of the closure operators fixes, and I don't see a way to do this in general. It seems necessary to dive into the specifics of the situation, which in this case are about fields. 

Comment: @Qiaochu: Okay, I see your point... Well, at least we can say in general that a set is closed (i.e. fixed under the closure operator, $\rho \lambda$, say) iff it is the $\rho$-image of some set. :)

Comment: It seems the link to Boyarchenko's paper is broken. Can you provide another link?

Comment: @DrewArmstrong: Fixed the link.